# Concurrency in Threads

Tags: c, concurrency, pthreads

I have an exam tomorrow on OS. And i have doubts with couple of the previous year questions.... I am not good with C

Explain why the code below is not optimal for concurrency. and how the code can be optimized..

```
void * func ( void * arg) 
{ 
printf("printing from thread %d\n",(int) arg); 
return null;
}
int main(void) 
{ 
    pthread_t threads[5];
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
          pthread_create( &(thread[i]), NULL, func, (void*) i);
          pthread_join( threads[i], NULL);
    } 
 return 0;
}
```

Second....

[image]

really appreciate any help.....

Answer (score 2):

In the first snippet you shouldn't join in the `for`. Joining right after creation will prevent concurrency: basically you have only one thread at any time and you're waiting for it. Join outside instead:

```
for(i = 0; i<5; i++)
      pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, func, (void*) i);

for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
      pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
```

#### EDIT (thanks R..)

Looking a third time at the second snippet it's apparent that the following can happen:

- The parent tries locks the mutex, signals the child and goes on to unlock and join. But the child is not waiting on the condition variable and the signal is lost.
- The child eventually locks the mutex and starts waiting.

Since no progress can be made, it's a deadlock.

Comment: Your analysis of the second snippet is wrong. `pthread_cond_wait` unlocks the mutex. The issue is the other way around: if the parent acquires the lock first, the signal will be lost, and the child will wait forever. This is why you need to lock the mutex before creating the child.

Comment: @R.. That's right, `pthread_cond_wait` unlocks the mutex - I edited my answer. But locking before starting the child thread will basically ensure the first signal is lost, no ?

Comment: Yes, good point. That's why correct use of condition variables **always** requires a predicate to be checked. There is simply no correct way to use them without one. If you want pure signaling, a semaphore, not a cond var, is the right sync object to use.

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, you do not start five threads to run simultaneous, instead you create one thread and wait for it to exit before you start the next.

For the second question, think about what happens if the thread locks the mutex first before the main function does it.

Comment: Thread locking it first is no problem. It's main locking it first that's problematic.